# Laravel compartilha sessão

Tags: laravel-5, session

Tenho um **sistema A** onde armazeno uma sessão

```
$login = $request->input( 'login' );
$request->$session()->put('login', $login );
```

E um **sistema B** que armazena a sessão:

```
$request->$session()->put('tentativa', 1);
```

Toda vez que seto o valor na sessão o **sistema B** a **sessão A** perde o valor

Lembrando que eles estão em pastas diferentes.

No **sistema A** o usuário só pode navegar no sistema se tiver logado

Não estou usando o `php artisan serve`

Estou usando o apache2.4 mesmo

Eu gostaria que isso não acontecesse, como faço para cada sistema usar sua respectiva sessão?

E lembrando que no **sistema B** não tem nenhuma variável de sessão do **sistema A**

Comment: Como você chama cada sistema!?

Comment: http://localhost:81/sistemaA e http://localhost:81/sistemaB

Comment: Então está explicado você está no mesmo spool de conexão e por isso um sistema anula o outro ... !!! na verdade está rodando tudo no mesmo serviço ... ou seja, compartilha sessão, etc ... !!! Tem que ser configurado outro host para o outro sistema! Não é problema no Laravel (que na verdade não há problema com o PHP) ... !

Comment: Como seria esse `outro host`?

Comment: http://www.raphaelfiga.com/desenvolvimento/instalando-configurando-virtualhost-apache-windows/ leia ...